# Ninject C# - Get concrete type at runtime from reading configuration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I want to select a particular binding based off a configuration value, for arguments sake, let's say I have two concrete classes called Action1 and Action2.  Currently I am passing in the Ninject kernel into a factory and returning the bound type based off that.

```
 public class ActionFactory: IActionFactory
    {
        public IAction GetAction(IKernel kernel, string actionName)
        {
            return kernel.Get<IAction>(actionName);
        }
    }
```

I am binding the actions in a Ninject Module like so:

```
Bind<IAction>().To<Action1>().Named("Action1");
Bind<IAction>().To<Action2>().Named("Action2");
```

Would it be possible for me to bind this without having to pass the kernel to a factory?

I do have the ability to refactor the workflow too, if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly inject the configured action and configure them conditional:

```
Bind<IAction>().To<Action1>().When(ctx => IsAction1Configured());
Bind<IAction>().To<Action2>().When(ctx => IsAction2Configured());
```

Comment: Hello Remo, thanks for replying.  I don't know if this is workable (or indeed even a possibility with Ninject) for me as the configuration is a complex type retrieved within a service and bindings are done on the initialization of the service without any knowledge of the configuration complex type which is retrieved in the service further down the stack.  I don't think what I want is possible, I may need to rethink my worflow.